# RESTful Route - best practice

Tags: rest, api, routes

Hopefully a quick question:

If I have a scenario where I have a car that can be rented out, which route would I use to view the booking for a car:

/bookings/car/:carID

Or

/cars/:carID/bookings

I can see how either can work but which one is a better way, because it’s booking that it’s returning should be via the Booking end point rather than the Car endpoint.

I think it reads better by navigating into the Car endpoint and then into bookings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct choice is: `/cars/:carID/bookings`

Here's a quote from the article (using your examples) [RESTful API Designing guidelines — The best practices](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9) for the reasoning why:

> [...] if we have resources under a resource, e.g bookings of a car,
>   then a few of the sample API endpoints would be:
>
> - `GET /cars/3/bookings` should get the list of all bookings of car 3
> - `GET /cars/3/bookings/45` should get the details of booking 45, which belongs to car 3
> - `DELETE /cars/3/bookings/45` should delete booking 45, which belongs to car 3
> - `POST /cars/3/bookings/` should create a new booking for car 3 and return the details of the new booking created

Here's another great article about the difference between RPC and RESTful services which also has really good examples: [Understanding RPC Vs REST For HTTP APIs](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/understanding-rest-and-rpc-for-http-apis/)

Here's the conclusion from that article (there's too much in the main part of the article to quote):

> One simple rule of thumb is this:
>
> - If an API is mostly actions, maybe it should be RPC.
> - If an API is mostly CRUD and is manipulating related data, maybe it should be REST.
>
> What if neither is a clear winner? Which approach do you pick?
>
> **Use Both REST And RPC Link**
>
> The idea that you need to pick one approach and have only one API is a
>   bit of a falsehood. An application could very easily have multiple
>   APIs or additional services that are not considered the "main" API.
>   With any API or service that exposes HTTP endpoints, you have the
>   choice between following the rules of REST or RPC, and maybe you would
>   have one REST API and a few RPC services.

> Knowing the differences between REST and RPC can be incredibly useful
>   when you are planning a new API, and it can really help when you are
>   working on features for existing APIs. It’s best not to mix styles in
>   a single API, because this could be confusing both to consumers of
>   your API as well as to any tools that expect one set of conventions
>   (REST, for example) and that fall over when it instead sees a
>   different set of conventions (RPC). Use REST when it makes sense, or
>   use RPC if it is more appropriate. Or use both and have the best of
>   both worlds!

Comment: Very helpful. Yeah I can see the logic, that’s what I thought as it reads in context. The thing is that the booking also contains a driver. So the booking includes a car and a driver. So the /car/5/bookings will only accept a GET request and POST will be sent to /bookings , DELETE and PATCH will be sent to /bookings/:bookingID

Comment: @Michael when booking a car with a driver `POST car/3/bookings` just needs the driver as one of the parameters. If you're not careful, things could start to get messy if you need to query the bookings of a driver for any car `driver/9/bookings`? Or even all bookings for the past day `bookings?period=1d`? But if you wanted to filter by driver too, `bookings?period=1d&driver=9` then `bookings?driver=9` should work too, shouldn't it? In my experience, refactor code to avoid code duplication. Multiple endpoints for the same thing is fine. Just keep everything organised/logical/clean.

Comment: Yep, that’s great! Thanks for this, has made it clear now.